# Google Map Info Windows Automatically Sizing, New Issue No Changes Made To Code

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

http://www.lindsaymantzel.com/googlemap/maptest12.html

Please see my map application. If you click on a red marker multiple times you will see that the info window is changing size until it's abnormally huge, then it all the other windows will be that size. I have a version of my code from 1 month ago, and 3 months ago on a different server that I know never had this issue. All three copies now demonstrate this issue. I can see that the element.style has an undesired height and when I try to edit it with chrome's developer tool it immediately changes the window back to the originally undesired height.

Since no code changes are made I have to assume that google api has changed or something along those lines but haven't found any documentation that may help me.

Comment: The google maps [experimental version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) (which you are using, as you don't specify a version) can change (and break) at any time.

Comment: How do I fix this? Is there a stable version, how do I specify the version?

Comment: Did you read the link in the documentation I provided?  Doesn't mean using the release or the frozen version will fix it permanently, the change you are seeing in the experimental version may eventually make it to the release and frozen versions (if it isn't a bug).

Comment: I added v=3 into the api link and I am still having this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't have the correct version specified. The most stable version is 3.17. Try changing your script import to :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.17&sensor=false"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `new google.maps.InfoWindow({ width: 500, height: 500 });` to set the size for information window.

Comment: No success with: `infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: popupContents,  width: 500, height: 500 });`

Comment: let me have a look at your code

Comment: view-source:http://www.lindsaymantzel.com/googlemap/maptest12.html

Comment: did you try to resize the photos inside your HTML? or you dont want to touch the photos?

Comment: If you inspect elements you can see that the div inside of the window has the propery heights and widths. It is the element.style for the inforwindow object that is changing.

Comment: in your maptest12.html line 765 where you have `infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: popupContents, maxWidth: 300});`  did you paste `width: 500, height: 500` inside the practises

Comment: There are no `width` or `height` properties in the [InfoWindowOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions)

Comment: You have `maxWidth: 300` in that line i think that is preventing your window from resizing

Comment: I've changed it now to width and height 500, still no success.

Comment: @geocodezip I just set the width and height to 500 as suggested to me with no success.

Comment: line 762: have you ever change the width for your images: `'<img src = "' + image +'" alt = "" width = "275px" /> <br>'+ information + `

Comment: @AmirHassanAzimi The width of the images isn't effecting the infowindow box. The div they are contained in has the proper height and width. The infowindow object styling is being altered.

Comment: I know for some reason infowindow's size  cannot be changed and I cant manipulate the js code from here